# What's the story with Element.getAttribute() for missing attributes?

Tags: xml, dom, w3c

I had always thought that XML DOM `Element.getAttribute(name)` was specified to return the empty string if the attribute does not exist. But I just read [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute), which say that browsers return `null`. It goes on to reference the [WhatWG spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-getattribute), which does indeed say that it should return `null`. But I go back to W3C's DOM Level 3 spec, and it says that the method should return the empty string.

So what's the real story? What's the real spec? Are WhatWG specifications really superseding W3C specifications for the DOM now? I haven't touched this stuff in a couple of years, so am I behind the times?

Answer (score 2):

The current version of the W3C DOM spec is [DOM4](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/). The behavior of `getAttribute` has changed in DOM4, so it seems that the W3C caught up with WHATWG. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model):

> Principal standardization of DOM was handled by the W3C, which last developed a recommendation in 2004. WHATWG took over development of the standard, publishing it as a **living document**. The W3C now publishes **stable snapshots** of the WHATWG standard.

[DOM Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#method-getAttribute), [DOM Level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-666EE0F9), [DOM Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-666EE0F9):

> **Return Value**
>
> The `Attr` value as a string, or the **empty string** if that attribute does not have a specified or default value.

[W3C DOM4](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-element-getattribute):

> Return the value of the first attribute in the context object's attribute list whose name is *name*, and **null** otherwise.

Comment: So an XML parser complying with DOM Level 2 would still be expected to return an empty string then, I suppose?

Comment: @GarretWilson If it claims to comply with DOM Level 2, yes.

Comment: All the above is accurate but on a side note: as far as the cited statement “The W3C now publishes **stable snapshots** of the WHATWG standard”, though that was true for a while until around the end of 2014, it’s no longer true. https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/ is no longer being maintained and no changes from the upstream https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/ spec have been ported to it since 2014 https://github.com/w3c/dom/commits/gh-pages